# How to assign an entity of type DTYPE to SWAP

Tags: c, pivot, quicksort, swap

This is sorting algorithm. I try to sort in descending order according to the size of the sum(x+y) of the fields which has x and y in struct.

I make the Quicksort descending order. but I have a question about `SWAP(A[N/2].sum, A[0].sum);` and `pivot`.

```
typedef struct DATA { double x; double y; double sum;} DTYPE;
//#define DTYPE double
#define SWAP(aa,bb) {DTYPE tmp; tmp = aa; aa=bb; bb=tmp;}

void sort_201821100(DTYPE A[], int N)
{
    int piv;
    
    if (N > 1) {
        piv = partition(A, N);
        sort_201821100(A, piv);
        sort_201821100(A + piv + 1, N - piv - 1);
    }
}

int partition(DTYPE A[], int N) {
    int P = N / 2;
    int i = 0, j = N;
    for (i = 0; i < j; i++)
    {
        A[i].sum = A[i].x + A[i].y;
    }

    DTYPE pivot;
    SWAP(A[N / 2].sum, A[0].sum);
    pivot = A[0].sum;
    while (1) {
        while ((A[++i].sum > pivot) && (i < N));
        while ((A[--j].sum < pivot) && (j > 0));
        if (i >= j) break;
        SWAP(A[i], A[j]);
    }
    SWAP(A[0], A[j]);
    return j;
}
```

SWAP can’t assign a value of type `Double` to an entity of type `DTYPE`.
And `pivot` needs an arithmetic form.
I want to know how to assign an entity of type DTYPE and put an arithmetic form.
Any reply will be thankful. Best regards.

Answer (score 1):

you should replace your SWAP-Macro by two functions

1. `void swap_dtype(DTYPE *a, DTYPE *b);`
   Then you can call `swap_dtype(A, A+j) instead of SWAP(A[0], A[j])`
2. `void swap_double(double *a, double *b);`
   Then you can call `swap_dtype(&(A[N / 2].sum), &(A[0].sum))` instead of `SWAP(A[0], A[j])`

If this works properly, you can replace this two function with a macro. Since macros are error prone, you should consider this step carefully.

You should also think hard about the swapping of the sums. An sorting algorithm should not modify the sorted elements only there position. This is counter intuitive.